# What's CloudWatch pricing for api and controllerManager logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

There's an [official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/control-plane-logs.html) about control plane logs in AWS. So imagine I turn it on and then there's this [pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/) where I can see the rate of `$0.50 per GB` when I click on `Logs` section. There're a lot of examples but I'm not sure if these are relevant except #8.

> Monthly ingested logs costs = $0.50 per GB of ingested logs * 8.47 GB of performance events as CloudWatch Logs = $4.23 per month

Is it a fair assumption that I'd pay `$0.50 per GB of ingested logs * ~1 Gb/mo = ~$0.5` for each cluster / month? I'm not sure how much data I can expect to receive from *api* and *controllerManager* logs.

Comment: That's the advertised price for CloudWatch Logs, and yes, that is the price you end up paying after configuring anything to use CloudWatch Logs.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/control-plane-logs.html) you linked to:

> When you use Amazon EKS control plane logging, you're charged standard Amazon EKS pricing for each cluster that you run. **You are charged the standard CloudWatch Logs data ingestion and storage costs for any logs sent to CloudWatch Logs from your clusters.** You are also charged for any AWS resources, such as Amazon EC2 instances or Amazon EBS volumes, that you provision as part of your cluster.

Your pricing formula also looks mostly right, although you seem to be missing the archival storage, which is roughly `$0.03 per GB per month` depending on your region. So depending on how long you want to retain the logs you'll have to add that as a component.

If you choose to forward the logs to another destination, this will also cost you money. See the [Vended Logs](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/) section on the pricing page.

Anecdotal evidence suggests that CloudWatch can get very expensive. Once you're at that point you might want to check out a [blog post](https://aws-blog.de/2021/02/analyzing-cloudwatch-costs.html) that my colleague wrote on analyzing CloudWatch costs (Disclaimer: this is my current employers techblog, but it's on topic).